# SQL Count of a Client where a manager id has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of events that contains the following following columns:

- EventID (PK),
- ClientID,
- EventDate,
- ManagerID,

Each time an event is created the ClientID along with a ManagerID and EventDate
So for instance:

```
 ManagerID  EventID  VolunteerID    ClientID    EventDate
 2358       2570036  276            19204       2016-01-18 00:00:00.000
```

However over time the ManagerID might be changed by a coordinator so  I need to find where a Clients Manager has changed in a given period.

So far I have :

```
SELECT Distinct [ManagerID]
  ,[EventID]
  ,[VolunteerID]
  ,[ClientID]
  ,[EventDate]

  FROM [Events]
  where EventDate > '2016-01-17 00:00:00.000'
  and Managerid >0
  group by ClientID
  ,ManagerID
  ,ClientId
  ,VolunteerID
  ,EventID
  ,EventDate
  order by EventDate DESC
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: 2005 I'm afraid  - although I have just upgraded the compability to 2008 as its it running SQL Server 10.50.1600

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `LAG()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             lag(managerid) over (partition by clientid order by eventdate) as prev_managerid
      from events e
     ) e
where prev_managerid <> managerid;
```

EDIT:

In earlier versions, you can use `outer apply`:

```
select e.*
from events e outer apply
     (select top1 e2.*
      from events e2
      where e2.clientid = e.clientid and e2.eventdate < e.eventdate
      order by e2.eventdate desc
     ) prev
where prev.managerid <> managerid;
```